# Magento 2 How to show count 0 on mini cart when no product is in cart?

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

Basically i want to show count on cart when no product is in cart.

[image]

Comment: Let me know if it'll not working for you

Comment: @usman please acknowledge the answer,if it is not working please comment it because here all community members do hard work to post answers. Your responsibility to response if anybody answer it

Comment: Yes it works for me

Answer (score 8):

You need to override **minicart.phtml** in your theme on below path :

**Copy From**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

**Paste To**

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Checkout/te‌​mplates/cart/minicar‌​t.phtml

Now, replace below code.

**From**

```
<span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

**To**

```
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
   <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko --></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
   <span class="counter-number">0</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Also update CSS:
`.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart .counter.qty.empty { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: The right way to do it. +1 for the answer.

Comment: <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') --> missing comma before summary_count

Comment: I think @NiravBhoi has right! The quoting <!-- ko if: getCartParam(summary_count') --> is wrong!!!! It should be <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') --> Otherwise the rendering of the minicart does not work properly!

But this solution is not working anymore on M2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

You can add below line in your **CSS** file

```
.counter.empty{display: block !important;}
```

and run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: This is not working when u access the page with a cleaed cache.  It renders nothing initally. After u add a product and remove it again from the cart it shows u the 0. But this is not the requirement here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is old and not working for M2.4.2 although the file replacements are correct but the code replacement is wrong.

**From**

```
    <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

**To**

```
    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <span class="counter-number">0</span>
    <!-- /ko -->´
```